# PHP not sending id

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that I wrote to look up an ID based on uniqueID

```
if ($_REQUEST['uniqueId'] != ""){
$qA = "SELECT id FROM customerdata WHERE uniqueId = \"". $_REQUEST['uniqueId']."\"";
$rA = mysql_query($qA);
list($id) = mysql_fetch_row($rA);
echo $id;
exit;

if ( mysql_num_rows ($rA) > 0) {

header('Location:response-en.php?id=$id');

    }
else
{
 header('Location:not-found.php');  
}
}
```

Rather than sending the user to response-en.php?id=1 it sends them to response-en.php?id=$id

Any idea why this is happening?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:
    `header('Location:response-en.php?id='.$id);`

**When you use a single quote: '**

This is a string literal. Everything (and I mean EVERYTHING) inside that string is taken wholesale. If you did this:  `$something = 'Location:response-en.php?id=$id';`, the value of `$something` is: `Location:response-en.php?id=$id` In order to add a variable into the string, you use the concatenation operator `.`.  Thus, the value of `$something` after `$something = 'Location:response-en.php?id='.$id;` would be `Location:response-en.php?id=5` (assuming $id = 5)
See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

**When you use double quote: "**

PHP will search inside your sting to find any variables. It will then replace the variable name with the value of the variable. If you did this:  `$something = "Location:response-en.php?id=$id";`, the value of `$something` is: `Location:response-en.php?id=5` - note the use of double quotes.
See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Also, I wanted to add that your script is vulnerable to [SQL-injection attack](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html). Always sanitize query-string values before using them in an SQL query. For more info on sanitizing values for sql, see the docs for [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score 2):

Variables inside a single-quoted string are not parsed. Variables inside double quotes are. Check out:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

You need double quotes to process variables in a string. Not single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing your string with double quotes instead of single quotes for correct variable parsing:

```
"Location:response-en.php?id=$id"
```

or use `complex syntax` with curly braces surrounding your variables:

```
"Location:response-en.php?id={$id}"
```

See [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `"` in stead of `'`

```
header("Location:response-en.php?id=$id");
```

or:

```
header('Location:response-en.php?id='.$id);
```